# SQL Server : Procedure, setting value for the variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Intending to update `Table6` with the following procedure. I have set variables and they are correctly addressed but how do I define value for the 2 types of variables. there are search variables and update variables

Procedure with condition if the cell has `NULL` value than add whatever the Variable has but if it already has value then leave its original value/don't overwrite it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Learning]

   @StartDate   DATE NULL,
   @EndDate     DATE NULL,
   @Data        VARCHAR(30) NULL,

   @Cond_CID    INT NOT NULL,
   @Cond_PID    INT NOT NULL,
   @Cond_SSC    VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL

AS
BEGIN   

BEGIN
    UPDATE temp.dbo.Table6
    SET StartDate = ISNULL(StartDate,@StartDate)
        ,EndDate = ISNULL(EndDate,@EndDate)
        ,Data = ISNULL(Data,@Data)
    WHERE Table6.CID = @Cond_CID AND TABLE6.PID = @Cond_PID AND TABLE6.SSC = @Cond_SSc
```

---

The table and data insert

```
CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table6
(
     CID INT NOT NULL,
     PID INT NOT NULL,
     SSC VARCHAR(3) NULL,
     StartDate DATE NULL,
     EndDate DATE NULL, 
     Data VARCHAR(30) NULL
     )

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table6
VALUES
(1001,  1333,'OP',  GETDATE(),  GETDATE(), 'OP2001156519952012'),
(1002,  1245,'OR',  GETDATE(),  NULL,      'OR20121005'),
(1003,  1116,'OP',  GETDATE(),  NULL,      'OP20131215'),
(1004,  1234,'OP',  GETDATE(),  GETDATE(), 'OP2001156519952012')

SELECT * FROM temp.dbo.Table6
```

sample data which has `null` values and this procedure will be used to populate data into the table.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your procedure? Why do you have 2 `BEGING` there?

Comment: well suppose im going to use it to update the null values, how would i do it? how do i use the variables to search a specific record and also set values for the variables which updates the data

Comment: Do you mean if the values you're searching by have a value of `NULL`? Like `CID` or `PID`? Considering that all of those parameters have a setting of `NOT NULL`, I *assume* that those columns can't have that value.

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking here, are you trying to create a _natively compiled stored procedure_ or asking on how to _execute a stored procedure_?

Comment: If I understand what are you trying to do here, you have two ways,1st one is to remove all the 3 `NOT NULL` for the search parameters, and check for `NULL`s in the body, if one of them `IS NULL` then `RAISEERROR` else do the job. The 2nd one is to **[`create a natively compiled stored procedure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-natively-compiled-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017)** then you can set your search parameters `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to prevent the (3) search parameters to be `NULL`s, but when you set those parameters as `NOT NULL` SQL Server will complain about it, and throw

> Msg 11555 Level 15 State 1 Line 7
>
> The parameter 'ParameterName' has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except for inline table-valued functions.

Also, I think your first 3 parameters shouldn't be `NULL` too, cause if you pass `NULL`s then your UPDATE won't do anything, just set your columns to `NULL` again.

You can check for `NULL`s in the body of your `SP`, and if one of them `IS NULL` then raise an error as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Learning]
(
   @StartDate   DATE,
   @EndDate     DATE,
   @Data        VARCHAR(30),

   @Cond_CID    INT,
   @Cond_PID    INT,
   @Cond_SSC    VARCHAR(3)
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@Cond_CID IS NULL OR @Cond_PID IS NULL OR @Cond_SSC IS NULL
      OR @StartDate IS NULL OR @EndDate IS NULL OR @Data IS NULL
     )
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Null values not allowed for the 3 last parameters!', 16, 1)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    UPDATE temp.dbo.Table6
    SET StartDate = ISNULL(StartDate,@StartDate)
        ,EndDate = ISNULL(EndDate,@EndDate)
        ,Data = ISNULL(Data,@Data)
    WHERE Table6.CID = @Cond_CID 
          AND 
          TABLE6.PID = @Cond_PID 
          AND 
          TABLE6.SSC = @Cond_SSc
  END
END
```

or by **[`Creating Natively Compiled Stored Procedures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-natively-compiled-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did have sql complaining with no clue. this is my 1st ever SP and although i like my progress lol but how are SP executed. I mean if i excute it , it will get stored but how can i used it to search record and update it? please

Comment: Although this works, actually passing `NULL` for the values won't actually cause the SP to update any rows, as `{Expression} = NULL` = `UNKNOWN != TRUE`.

Comment: @Larnu True, but if you read my answer, I suggest to check all the 6 parameters for `NULL`s. Not just the 3 search parameters.

Comment: @ZabiSidiqkhil I'm not sure I get this part _it will get stored but how can i used it to search record and update it?_ of your comment, what you mean? A stored procedure is a set of Structured Query Language (SQL) statements with an assigned name, which are stored in a relational database management system as a group, so it can be reused and shared by multiple programs. So you SP will be stored in your database when you create it, not when you execute it.

Comment: OK so they are meant to be executed by tools such as Report Manage which I used in a company to filter data of reports by dates or company etc. is that what you mean? They cannot be used as they are in sql server. becuase thats what was giving me a headach  since yesterday. thinking like ok i created it but now how do i use it lol.